# Executing a command line command from a simple batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I am very new to this so a simplified explanation would be appreciated.

I am trying to make a batch file that executes the following command in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\delta\dc2.exe -configure="C:\Users\delta\Switch.xml"
```

So far i have tried putting the follwing in a .bat but i have had no luck:

```
START cmd.exe /k "C:\Users\delta\dc2.exe -configure="C:\Users\delta\Switch.xml""
```

I simply get the command prompt popping up for a fraction of a second and then it disappears. (Can't read what it says)

Any ideas on where i am going wrong?

Comment: add a "pause" line to make the window stay open and wait for input from you.  The error, if any, is likely your best hint right now

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to be using the START command.  The reason I typically find the START command may be quite useful is for running a program in the background, which may not be the desired action if you're trying to see results.  Just make a new text file that says:

> @Echo Off
> C:\Users\delta\dc2.exe -configure="C:\Users\delta\Switch.xml"
> pause

Make sure that the filename ends with ".bat", e.g. "rundc2.bat"
Then, from the command line, run: "rundc2"
(The ".bat" is optional, when you're running the program.)

Answer (score 0):

#### Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

```
START cmd.exe /k "C:\Users\delta\dc2.exe -configure="C:\Users\delta\Switch.xml""
```

Your start command is wrong.

The first argument should be the title of the command (it is not optional).

Try:

```
START "my command title" "C:\Users\delta\dc2.exe" -configure=C:\Users\delta\Switch.xml
```

or

```
START "" "C:\Users\delta\dc2.exe" -configure=C:\Users\delta\Switch.xml
```

---

#### Syntax

```
START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
```

Key:

```
title       Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
path        Starting directory.
command     The command, batch file or executable program to run.
parameters  The parameters passed to the command.
```

...

> Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like "My Script" or just a pair of empty quotes ""
>
> According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).